# Ideas on timing class initialization

Tags: python, performance

I have lots of classes. Some of them are slow to initialize, and I want to delay some of the initialization by using [cached properties](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576563-cached-property/). The first step is to identify which are the culprits. So I want to time the following code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, ....):
        # start measurement
        ...
        # end measurement, report
```

My requirements are:

- timing results as log entries.
- as little intrusive as possible
- I want to keep it in my code, but be able to disable it with a flag

So my first idea is to implement a generic `timeme` function:

```
def timeme(func):    
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        start = # get start timestamp
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = # get end timestamp
        # report timespan
        return result
    return f
```

(which could be used to time any kind of function, not only class methods)

And now I can do:

```
class MyClass:

    @timeme
    def __init__(self, ....):
    ...
```

Is there a more *pythonic*  way of doing this? Some standard library support for this? Tooling support? Any obvious shortcomings of this approach?

Comment: A single word comes to mind: //profiling//.

Comment: Sure, but I want to concentrate on specific areas. I do not want a full and complicated profiler report. And by having this is the code, I can enable it in production if I feel like, having it in the logs with real-life activity - not by reproducing the use case with a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like this in the standard library, except `cProfile` for regular profiling.

What I would recommend for you is to create a simple metaclass, that will wrap `__init__` methods if some global/environment variable is set.  That way you won't need to clutter your code with debug/profiling decorators.

Just a starting point (haven't tested it):

```
import functools

# Python 3.3 for time.monotonic is required
import time

class TimedMeta(type):
    timing_enabled = True

    @classmethod
    def _wrap_timeit(mcls, cls_name, meth):
        @functools.wraps(meth)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.monotonic()
            try:
                return meth(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                end = time.monotonic()
                mcls._record_timing(cls_name, end - start)

    @classmethod
    def _record_timing(mcls, cls_name, timing):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, dct):
        if mcls.timing_enabled:
            try:
                init = dct['__init__']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                dct['__init__'] = mcls._wrap_timeit(name, init)

        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, dct)

class Timed(metaclass=TimingMeta):
    pass

class Foo(Timed):
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(1.0)
```